# Using hyperref package with index, pdf vs. manuscript pages

Tags: hyperref

I am using the hyperref package with the following options:

```
  \usepackage[breaklinks=true,
              hypertexnames=false,
              linktocpage,
              plainpages=false,
              pdfpagelabels]{hyperref}
```

I need to select `hypertexnames=false`, as otherwise links to theorems, definitions, etc., go to the wrong chapter.  (I.e., a link to Theorem 1.9 might go to Theorem 8.9).

However, if I select `hypertexnames=false`, the links in my index go to the pdf page--and not the book page (which, due to front matter, may be more than a 10 page difference).  I.e., if I select in the index "Topic X p. 312" it m

Answer (score 2):

You'll need to provide more of a minimal working example to show the problem. With the following (admittedly different from your preamble), I don't see the problem:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage[thref,hyperref]{ntheorem}
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}[chapter]

\begin{document}

\frontmatter
\tableofcontents

\addtheoremline*{example}{\vspace{\baselineskip}\hspace{-\leftmargini}\bfseries{List of theorems}}
\listtheorems{theorem}

\mainmatter
\chapter{One}
Here's a theorem:
\begin{theorem}[First Theorem]\label{one}
Something in the first theorem
\end{theorem}

As seen in \thref{one} but not in \thref{two}, \ldots

\chapter{Two}
Here's another theorem:
\begin{theorem}[Second Theorem]\label{two}
Something in the second theorem
\end{theorem}

As seen in \thref{two} but not in \thref{one}, \ldots

\end{document}
```

[image]

I don't know about making an index of theorems, but the list of theorems I have there has correct page numbers and links.

Comment: Any idea why `1.1` is showing up under `Chapter 2` in the TOC?  Or am I missing something?

Comment: It's a list of theorems following the ToC. Probably should have included a header making that more obvious.

Comment: I've added a more explicit title to the list of theorems now.